# dotnetnuke redirect

Tags: dotnetnuke

how can i redirect in dotnetnuke 5.3 +  to a particular page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotNetNuke API is having helper methods for navigation. See `DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL` method overloads.

Depending on the various requirements, developers are using this method. for example, if you want to redirect to tab id 80 then you can simply write DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(80) and it will redirect user to tab id 80

Please add more details about what you exactly want to implement so that I can point you towards some sample.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: how can i redirect to a particle page in a module like i am on viewdata module page , i want to go to the details page in that module ? how can i do that?

Comment: ok then you can use Response.Redirect(EditUrl()) method of hte same class. see this link http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/111/threadid/184394/scope/posts/Default.aspx

Comment: NavigateURL allows you to specify a variety of parameters including the ControlKey, which is what you would use to specify the key of the control that you want to be displayed by the module.

Answer (score 1):

`DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL()` does not do a redirect, it simply creates a target URL based on the parameter you've provided.

Once you get that URL, you can either assign it to a hyperlink, or do a `Response.Redirect()` with it

Answer (score 0):

If the included URL Rewriter doesn't do it for you, you can use Snapsis PageBlaster or the commercial iFinity Url Master Module (http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Url_Master_DNN_SEO_Urls). On a deeper level and if you are on IIS7, you can use the URL Rewrite function there.

Otherwise, you can try this:

1. Go to the page you want to redirect, page functions, settings
2. Find Advanced settings and then Other settings
3. Click the radio button "URL (Link to an external resource)" and fill the Location field

Comment: Well i am talking about simple redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can get TabID (Page ID) in c#/Vb.
Pass tab ID to function DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(TabID)
This will return URL.